# AngularJS - ng-bind-html-unsafe and ng-model Problems

Tags: angularjs

I have the following line in my html:

`<div ng-bind-html-unsafe="departmentConfig" class="control-group"></div>`

and I use a `$resource` get to retrieve the HTML, assign the HTML to `$scope.departmentConfig`, and then the view is updated perfectly.  The HTML that is assigned to `$scope.departmentConfig` contains form elements, with `ng-model` attributes in it, but when I change the values in these input elements, they don't update the `$scope` model at all.

This is what I have tried, based on a lot of other internet posts, and it isn't working:

```
$resource('resources/sources/departments/:mappedName', {
        mappedName:departmentKey
    }).get(function(departmentConfig) {
        // This will call another function that will build a chunk of HTML
        $scope.departmentConfig = $scope.buildDepartmentConfigHtml(departmentConfig);
        // This is my feeble attempt to access the element, and bootstrap it to include the items in the $scope model.
        var $departmentConfigContainer = $('#departmentConfig');
        angular.bootstrap($departmentConfigContainer, ['sourcemanager']);
```

I have even seen some jsFiddle examples where this appears to be working, but mine isn't.  Am I calling bootstrap too soon?  I also tried putting a `$watch` on `$scope.departmentConfig` like this:

```
$scope.$watch('departmentConfig', function() {
    var $departmentConfigContainer = $('#departmentConfig');
    angular.bootstrap($departmentConfigContainer);
});
```

but it didn't work either.  I bet there is an easy explanation to this, I just can't seem to get the input elements with `ng-model` that are loaded after page compile to get bound to the model.  Any help is appreciated, this is the last piece of functionality I need to get working on my page.  Let me know if you need more information about my configuration as well.

So, simply put, how can I force a section of the DOM to recompile after I know it has been loaded?

**UPDATE**

Here is a jsfiddle outlining what I would like to do: http://jsfiddle.net/j_snyder/ctyfg/.  You will notice that property two and three don't update the model, and I am calling bootstrap on the outer div, hoping that will include those in the model binding.  This is the first time I have posted to jsfiddle, please let me know if you can't see the example.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

ng-bind-html is made for regular HTML, not compiling new angular elements.

You will have use the [$compile service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile).

Here is how you would edit your current example to work: http://jsfiddle.net/andytjoslin/ctyfg/21/.  But this way ends up being bad, because you have to do DOM manipulation in your controller.

You just need to create a directive that will basically do what you wanted ng-bind-html to do: http://jsfiddle.net/andytjoslin/ctyfg/22/

Comment: Thanks Andy.  I also posted on the Angular Google Group, and here is the thread.  I got something working that will indeed do what I need, along the lines you just posted.  https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/angular/51-CNL6GEKE