# Dealing with Django model forms + REST Framework with Angularjs Single Page Application

Tags: django, angularjs, single-page-application, django-rest-framework, django-forms

I'm trying to implement a [SPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) in my existing Django project with [Angularjs](https://angularjs.org/). I have setup the start of a API using [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) to retrieve my data in angular.

Some of my django model forms have a lot of complexity in them and would love to somehow pass it to the client side.

I could be wrong here but since I'm setting this project up as a SPA, once I send the user to the project from my django `urls.py`, then the angular routing via `$routeProvider` take over and talk to all my angular stuff to get data (controllers, services, etc.,) via the REST api. This then prevents me from sending my form over via context.

Every example I've seen with angularjs and django forms always explicitly writes out each field in the form. Is there anyway for me to get my django model form that has a bunch of code in its `__init__` method, over to the client side without having to set each field manually?

Comment: This link here solved my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18157305/angularjs-compiling-dynamic-html-strings-from-database/18157958#18157958

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never tried this, but here's how I'd start on trying to do it.

You can use the in-built as_p(), as_ul() and as_table() methods of the form to pass the form HTML from the REST API, e.g.

```
class MyApiView(ApiView):
    def get(self, request, format=None):
        form = MyForm()
        response['form_html'] = my_form.as_ul()

        return Response(response)
```

You would then need to build the form skeleton and submit buttons in Angular, then insert form_html as the form body just as you would do in a standard django template.

Disclaimer: It's been a while since I've properly used django-rest-framework so the syntax in my example mught not be correct, but the basic idea is there

Comment: That gave me some legs to run with but unfortuantly I ran into a roadblock with angular rules with HTML noted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296193/angularjs-ng-bind-html-unsafe-and-ng-model-problems